# How to get tcbox to break to a new line when it overflows the page?

Tags: packages, line-breaking, tcolorbox, overflow

As demonstrated in the code below, when the tcbox overflows the page horizontally it does not automatically move itself into a new line:

```
This is some text to fill the empty space before the box. Some more text 1234.
\tcbox[on line]{The tcbox overflows the page 123456789.}
Text after the box.
```

[image]

I can manually move it to a new line by using `\\`:

```
This is some text to fill the empty space before the box. Some more text 1234.\\
\tcbox[on line]{The tcbox overflows the page 123456789.}
Text after the box.
```

[image]

However this is a hassle as I have to constantly check whether my tcboxes are overflowing whenever I make changes to my text.

Is there a way for the entire tcbox to automatically render onto a new line if it overflows the page without me manually having to `\\` it?

Thanks.

Edit for Steven:

Whilst that macro does work there seems to be some serious problems with the tabto commands messing up tcbox vertical spacing.

```
~\\
This is some text to fill the empty space before the box. Some more text 1234.
\tcbox[on line]{The tcbox overflows the page 123456789.} This is more text.
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa space aaaaaa 
\tcbox[on line]{tcbox on the line below.}
Text after the box.

~\\
This is some text to fill the empty space before the box. Some more text 1234.
\tccheckbox{The tcbox overflows the page 123456789.} This is more text.
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa space aaaaaa \tccheckbox{tcbox on the line below.}
Text after the box.
```

[image]

As you can see using a tcbox on the line below after using the tabto commands causes it to clip into the one above it whereas without using tabto the vertical spacing is correct.

Comment: Could you please post your LaTeX code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I save the box before typesetting it and measure its width.  I use the `tabto` package to determine the distance to the end of line and compare to the box width.

I also used `\sloppy` because the tcbox size is a very clumsy thing to typeset inline.

EDITED to address the issue of overlap.  One must understand that the `\tabto` invocations essentially break the typesetting of a paragraph, which otherwise resolves the vertical space issues of the tcboxes.  So what I did to remedy this issue is to typeset a zero-width rule of the tcbox vertical footprint immediately *before* and immediately *after* performing the `\tabto` sequence.

The good news is that this resolves the vertical overlap issue.  The (potentially) bad news is that it will no longer necessarily typeset identically to the sequence in the absence of `\tabto` invocations.  Again, the reason is that whenever a `\tabto` is invoked, that unadjusted location is fixed and can no longer shift horizontally as part of paragraph margination.  So text before that point is typeset as a paragraph ending at that point, and text subsequent to the tcbox begins a new sequence of text justification.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5in,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox,tabto}
\newcommand\tccheckbox[2][on line]{%
  \sbox0{\tcbox[#1]{#2}}%
  \rule[-\dp0]{0pt}{\dimexpr\dp0+\ht0}%
  \tabto*{\linewidth}%
  \ifdim\dimexpr\linewidth-\TabPrevPos > \wd0\relax
    \tabto*{\TabPrevPos}%
  \else
    \tabto{0pt}%
  \fi    
  \copy0%
  \rule[-\dp0]{0pt}{\dimexpr\dp0+\ht0}%
  \allowbreak
}
\begin{document}
\sloppy
Some text before the box. 
\tccheckbox{The tcbox overflows the page 123456789.}
Text after the box.

\bigskip This is some text to fill the empty space before the box. 
\tccheckbox{The tcbox overflows the page 123456789.}
Text after the box.

~\\
This is some text to fill the empty space before the box. Some more text 1234.
\tcbox[on line]{The tcbox overflows the page 123456789.} This is more text.
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa space aaaaaa 
\tcbox[on line]{tcbox on the line below.}
Text after the box.

~\\
This is some text to fill the empty space before the box. Some more text 1234.
\tccheckbox{The tcbox overflows the page 123456789.} This is more text.
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa space aaaaaa \tccheckbox{tcbox on the line below.}
Text after the box.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please see my edit to the question about vertical spacing using this macro.

Comment: @Tristan Please see my edit and "fix"

Comment: While \raggedright is nicer for not having the mentioned horizontal spacing typesetting changes, this solution still works very nicely and it works with justified text which is an advantage. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

A possible solution using `\raggedright` of `ragged2e.sty`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5in,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
This is some text to fill the empty space before the box. 
\tcbox[on line]{The tcbox overflows the page 123456789.}
Text after the box.
\lipsum[1][1-5]

\bigskip This is some text to fill the empty space before the box. 
\justifying
\tcbox[on line]{The tcbox overflows the page 123456789.}
Text after the box.
\lipsum[1][1-5]

\bigskip This is some text to fill the empty space before the box. 
\raggedright
\tcbox[on line]{The tcbox overflows the page 123456789.}
Text after the box.
\lipsum[1][1-5]

\bigskip This is some text to fill the empty space before the box. 
\raggedleft
\tcbox[on line]{The tcbox overflows the page 123456789.}
Text after the box.
\lipsum[1][1-5]
\end{document}
```